# Any way to select an item in a Picker on Android using Detox?

Tags: android, react-native, detox

According to the [docs](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md) the method for selecting a value is only available to IOS. Is there any suggested workaround for Android?

Answer (score 2):

```
await waitFor(element(by.id('android_touchable_wrapper'))).toBeVisible()

await element(by.id('android_picker_headless').withAncestor(by.id('android_touchable_wrapper'))).atIndex(0).tap()

await element(by.text('Picker Value Dropdown 1')).tap()
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a testID field to the picker:

```
<Picker testID='test-picker'>
  ...
</Picker>
```

Then handled the selection as follows:

```js
if (global.device.getPlatform() === 'ios') {
  await element(by.id('test-picker')).setColumnToValue(0, 'First item');
} else {
  // Android
  await element(by.id('test-picker')).tap();
  await element(by.text('First item')).tap()
}
```

You could create a reusable function to handle this in future:

```js
const selectPicker = async (pickerId, text, value = 0) => {
  if (global.device.getPlatform() === 'ios') {
    await element(by.id(pickerId)).setColumnToValue(value, text);
  } else {
    // Android
    await element(by.id(pickerId)).tap();
    await element(by.text(text)).tap();
  }
}
```

Then reference it wherever you need:

```js
await selectPicker('test-picker', 'First item', 0);
```